# Disable "Sandbox mode" - Apple In app purchase?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

So basically I'm doing this the first time. I've made test account in itunes connect to test in-app purchases. It all works well with that particular account, but when I sign in, with my real Apple ID, i still get message "Environment: Sandbox" underneath.

[image]

Any idea how to disable this?

Answer (score 2):

Remove your account from "Users and Roles" in "iTunes Connect" and add him to default test flight testers.